# ('Input has undefined rank:', TensorShape(None)) <- Error in Building ResNet

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am getting an undefined rank error, while building ResNet; I have mentioned a **reproducible** code below:

Here is my Identity Block:

```
def IdentityBlock(X, f, filters):
    
    F1, F2, F3 = filters
    X_shortcut = X
    
    X = Conv2D(filters = F1, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'valid')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    
    X = Conv2D(filters = F2, kernel_size = (f, f), padding = 'same')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    
    X = Conv2D(filters = F3, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'same')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    
    X = Add()([X, X_shortcut])
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    
    return X
```

Here is my Convolution Block

```
def ConvBlock(X, f, filters):
    
    F1, F2, F3 = filters
    X_shortcut = X
    
    X = Conv2D(filters = F1, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'valid')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    
    X = Conv2D(filters = F2, kernel_size = (f, f), padding = 'same')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    
    X = Conv2D(filters = F3, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'same')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    
    X_shortcut = Conv2D(filters = F3, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'same')
    X_shortcut = BatchNormalization()(X_shortcut)
    
    X = Add()([X, X_shortcut])
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    
    return X
```

And my resnet model:

```
def ResNet(input_shape = (224, 224, 3)):
    X_input = Input(input_shape)
    
    X = Conv2D(64, (7, 7))(X_input)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    X = MaxPooling2D((3, 3))(X)
    
    X = ConvBlock(X, f = 3, filters = [64, 64, 128])
    X = IdentityBlock(X, 3, filters = [64, 64, 128])
    X = IdentityBlock(X, 3, filters = [64, 64, 128])
    
    X = ConvBlock(X, f = 3, filters = [128, 128, 512])
    X = IdentityBlock(X, 3, filters = [128, 128, 512])
    X = IdentityBlock(X, 3, filters = [128, 128, 512])
    X = IdentityBlock(X, 3, filters = [128, 128, 512])
    
    X = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(X)
    model = Model(input = X_input, output = X)
    
    return model
```

When I call RenNet Like this:

```
base_model = ResNet50(input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-f81766b0bb4e> in <module>
----> 1 base_model = ResNet50(input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

<ipython-input-21-309ae6f634f4> in ResNet50(input_shape)
      7     X = MaxPooling2D((3, 3))(X)
      8 
----> 9     X = ConvBlock(X, f = 3, filters = [64, 64, 128])
     10     X = IdentityBlock(X, 3, filters = [64, 64, 128])
     11     X = IdentityBlock(X, 3, filters = [64, 64, 128])

<ipython-input-20-aeab857c5df6> in ConvBlock(X, f, filters)
     16 
     17     X_shortcut = Conv2D(filters = F3, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'same')
---> 18     X_shortcut = BatchNormalization()(X_shortcut)
     19 
     20     X = Add()([X, X_shortcut])
.
.
.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/normalization.py in build(self, input_shape)
    296     input_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(input_shape)
    297     if not input_shape.ndims:
--> 298       raise ValueError('Input has undefined rank:', input_shape)
    299     ndims = len(input_shape)
    300 

ValueError: ('Input has undefined rank:', TensorShape(None))
```

Comment: That ResNet block name is actually `ResNet50`, I accidentally changed it.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the `Conv2D` operation to the `BatchNormalization` Layer instead of a tensor. Try changing

```
X_shortcut = Conv2D(filters = F3, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'same')
```

to

```
X_shortcut = Conv2D(filters = F3, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'same')(X_shortcut)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work. Now it's showing me this error: `TypeError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f93dad5b550>`

Comment: Is that error in the same line as the one before?

Answer (score 0):

These were the steps I followed to reach the final solution:

1 - the add function works like add([x,x_shortcut]) , im not too sure about the other way.

2 - Made a change in the variable, instead of using X in the IdentityBlock Function I changed it to input_

3 - The shape of the inputs in the add layer we not in the desired way, so I
played around with the kernel size and stride values (not too good at these)
to make that layer work. Did this for the ConvBlock and IdentityBlock.

4 - Final small error was when calling the keras model its Model(inputs = , outputs = ), input and output don't work.

```
def IdentityBlock(input_, f, filters):
    
        F1, F2, F3 = filters

        X = Conv2D(filters = F1, kernel_size = (1, 1), padding = 'valid') (input_)
        X = BatchNormalization()(X)
        X = Activation('relu')(X)

        X = Conv2D(filters = F2, kernel_size = (f, f), padding = 'same')(X)
        X = BatchNormalization()(X)
        X = Activation('relu')(X)

        X = Conv2D(filters = F3, kernel_size = (1, 1), padding = 'same')(X)
        X = BatchNormalization()(X)

        X = add([X, input_])
        X = Activation('relu')(X)

        return X
```

```
def ConvBlock(X, f, filters):
    
        F1, F2, F3 = filters
        X_shortcut = X
    
        X = Conv2D(filters = F1, kernel_size = (1, 1),strides = (1,1), padding 
        = 'valid')(X)
        X = BatchNormalization()(X)
        X = Activation('relu')(X)
    
        X = Conv2D(filters = F2, kernel_size = (f, f), padding = 'same')(X)
        X = BatchNormalization()(X)
        X = Activation('relu')(X)
    
        X = Conv2D(filters = F3, kernel_size = (1, 1), padding = 'same')(X)
        X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    
        X_shortcut = Conv2D(filters = F3,padding = 'same' , kernel_size = (1,1) 
        , strides = (1,1))(X_shortcut)
        X_shortcut = BatchNormalization()(X_shortcut)
    
        X = add([X, X_shortcut])
        X = Activation('relu')(X)
    
        return X
```

```
def ResNet(input_shape = (224, 224, 3)):

  X_input = Input(input_shape)
  X = ZeroPadding2D((3,3))(X_input)

  X = Conv2D(64, (7, 7) , strides = (2,2))(X_input)
  X = BatchNormalization()(X)
  X = Activation('relu')(X)

  X = ZeroPadding2D((1,1))(X)
  X = MaxPooling2D((3, 3) , strides = (2,2))(X)

  X = ConvBlock(X, f = 3, filters = [64, 64, 128])
  X = IdentityBlock(X, 3, filters = [64, 64, 128])
  X = IdentityBlock(X, 3, filters = [64, 64, 128])

  X = ConvBlock(X, f = 3, filters = [128, 128, 512])
  X = IdentityBlock(X, 3, filters = [128, 128, 512])
  X = IdentityBlock(X, 3, filters = [128, 128, 512])
  X = IdentityBlock(X, 3, filters = [128, 128, 512])

  model = Model(inputs = X_input, outputs = X)
```

I hope it helped!